# Accessing a Spotify user's subscription level in apps API

Tags: api, spotify

Is there a way to access a user's subscription level in any of the Spotify APIs (most likely apps), either explicitly or implicitly (e.g. premium users can only have certain type of attributes)?

It doesn't look like there's any such information in the user profile:
https://developer.spotify.com/docs/apps/api/1.0/api-models-user.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `product` property of the [Session](https://developer.spotify.com/docs/apps/api/1.0/api-models-session.html):

```js
require([
  '$api/models',
], function(models) {
  models.session.load('product')
    .done(function(s) {
      console.log(s.product); // e.g. "premium"
    });
});
```